# return readline to its original state when recieving SIGINT

Tags: c, bash, gnu, readline

In bash when a user hits <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> (sending SIGINT) it takes back readline to its original state canceling search/vi-mode/... state.

I tried `UNSETSTATE` macro but it has no effect, actually even `SETSTATE` has no effect on the state of readline, however the `rl_readline_state` variable is changed.

In signal handler I tried:

```c
RL_UNSETSTATE(RL_STATE_ISEARCH|RL_STATE_NSEARCH|RL_STATE_SEARCH|RL_STATE_VIMOTION|RL_STATE_NUMERICARG|RL_STATE_MULTIKEY);
```

I tried `rl_redisplay()` but nothing works.
Keep in mind that I have:

```
rl_catch_signals = 0;
```

I have a handler for `rl_getc_function`.

Here is my code:
https://gitlab.com/abellaismail/minishell/-/blob/dev/src/sig_handler.c

Comment: There is no code to comment on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/abellaismail/minishell/-/blob/dev/src/sig_handler.c

Answer (score 3):

I knew it had to do with 42 in some way.
[Here's](https://github.com/carce-bo42/42_minishell)  my repo for the project, if you want to look further into how exactly the solution I found works.
Assuming your question applies when the prompt is waiting for a command and you press ctrl + C (when on heredoc or executing childs processes the behaviour is a bit different), I called the following function:

```
void    ft_signal_ctrl_c(int sig)
{
    (void)sig;
    write(2, "\n", 1);
    rl_replace_line("", 0);
    rl_on_new_line();
    rl_redisplay();
}
```

This succesfully goes back to the shell while (running) loop, showing a new prompt. errno should be updated separately too (ctrl+ C gives $? = 1).

Comment: when I press C-r readline shows a prompt for history search, bash in case of C-c will unset state of search to original state.
btw my sigaction doesn't set SA_RESTART in flags which means that execve will not block the handler.

Comment: This adaptation worked for me in Perl `$SIG{INT} = sub { print("\n"); $tty->replace_line('', 0); $tty->on_new_line(); $tty->redisplay() };`